# How to set identifier "Listing 1" in listing in bold

Tags: floats, listings, captions

I use figures and listings in a document. By default, the identifier "Figure 1" is set in bold, while "Listing 1" is normal. For consistent looks I would like to have either everythin bold or normal. How?

**edit:** MWE (without the solution):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
language=C
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
   caption={[short] long long long.},
   label={lst1}
]
int main ( void )
{
   return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Documentclass is IOS-Book-Article which is based on article as far as I can tell. You find it [here](http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/52/98/48/TEX/IOS-Book-Article.cls)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you are using `listing` package, probably  `\renewcommand{\listingname}{\bfseries Listing}` will do the job. Otherwise MWE is required.

Comment: @blackburn: Thank you. I was preparing a MWE while you answered ;). The correct line is ´\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{{\bfseries Listing}}´. Your answer lead me to search for the right words. Make it an answer to accept that.

Comment: now the number is not printed bold, but I'll figure that out...

Comment: @steffen: Give: `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\bfseries Listing}` instead of `\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{{\bfseries Listing}}`. The extra grouping inside definition prevents that bold.

Comment: @blackburn: without the double braces, the rest of the caption is also bold. I wanted only the word "Listing" and the number to be bold.

Comment: No, the identifier "Figure 1" is *not* set in bold by default, so how to you do that?

Comment: ...and by the way, `\usepackage[bf]{caption}` would be a possible solution, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{\bfseries Listing}
\makeatletter
\def\fnum@lstlisting{%
  \lstlistingname
  \ifx\lst@@caption\@empty\else~\thelstlisting\normalfont\fi}%
\makeatother
```

In `listings` package, `\fnum@lstlisting` macro makes the caption name and number bold. But, to make the rest of the caption non-bold, we need to add `\normalfont` in this definition.

Comment: Add `{\bfseries` before `\lstlistingname` and `}` after \fi; this avoids redefining `\lstlistingname` and issuing `\normalfont`.